# Laravel Horizon Dashboard Explanation

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

[image]

Hi All, I know its a very basic and generic question but had no choice but to ask, The highlighted options, what are these and how do they appear and what do they represent. This is a general image taken from a web article.

Answer (score 1):

I've never fiddled much with horizon personally, so please bear with me. It would appear that the `colorful-mountain-ree5ob2u-worker-1-Ro2v` and `colorful-mountain-ree5ob2u-worker-2-uz4R` are representative of the machine/environment name(s) on which horizon is running.

This is an example I took from the Laravel/Horizon GitHub page:
[image: official laravel horizon documentation example]

And this is an example screenshot from my local Homestead environment:
[image]

They appear on the Horizon page on your Laravel application `yoururlhere.test/horizon` by running the following command `php artisan horizon`.

The workers themselves are found in the horizon.php configuration file and are set up like this:

```
    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 3,
            'tries' => 1,
        ],
    ],
```

The name also appears to be appended by a seemingly random 4-character text string, which changes every time the `php artisan horizon` command is ran.

Comment: Thats my assumption too, but I cant find something documented about this or any article mentioning this